# Reading data from Hbase using Get command in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I want to read data from an Hbase table using get command while I have also the key of the row..I want to do that in my Spark streaming application, Is there any source code someone can share?

Comment: I don't think you can use Spark streaming for this. But you can read Hbase table using Spark newHadoopAPI which returns RDD or using any connector like HortonWorks Hbase connector which returns DataFrame or using Phoenix Spark API.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spark `newAPIHadoopRDD` to read Hbase table, which returns and RDD.

**For example:**

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Hbase").setMaster("local")
val sc = new SparkContext(sparkConf)
val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
val tableName = "table"

conf.set("hbase.master", "localhost:60000")
conf.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", "localhost:2181")
conf.set("zookeeper.znode.parent", "/hbase-unsecure")
conf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tableName)


val rdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])
println("Number of Records found : " + rdd.count())
sc.stop()
```

Or you can use any Spark Hbase connector like HortonWorks Hbase connector.

https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc

You can also use Spark-Phoenix API.

https://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html